# Cloudformation stack template status is ROLLBACK_COMPLETE and unable to update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

[image]
[image]

I've currently been trying to follow the AWS Workshops guide for the 'Amazon Labs for PostgreSQL'.

The first prerequisite is to create a Cloudformation template using the template provided (see here: https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/098605dc-8eee-4e84-85e9-c5c6c9e43de2/en-US/1-prereq/i-need-to-deploy-lab-environment-manually/setup-with-aurora-pg)

However, the creation process consistently ends up failing. The two images above show the errors I'm receiving.

I know that template creation should work (and has previously) given that the role I'm using has PowerUser rights so CF is possible for myself. Are there any other reasons as to why this failure could be occurring?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error you're getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yep, I've added a screenshot of the error I'm receiving after attempting to create the stack on AWS. Apologies for not doing this before.

Answer (score 0):

in your template `aupglabsGDBstack` resource attribute
`Properties.OwnerArn` is a string that says `Specify Cloud9 owner ARN` instead of an actual arn of the cloud9 owner. Make sure to add a valid Arn:

```
  aupglabsGDBstack:
    Properties:
      OwnerArn: <insert-valid-arn>
```